# How to emit a sequence of mappings with extra newlines in yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I want to emit a seqence of mappings using the yaml-cpp library in the following format:

```
-
  name: <some_name>
  value: <some_value>
```

I'm using this code:

```
Emitter out;
out << YAML::BeginSeq;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < prof_info_.numOfSettings; ++i)
{
   str = NvUS_to_string(stgs[i].settingName);

   if (str != "")
   {
      out << YAML::BeginMap;

      out << YAML::Key << "name";
      out << YAML::Value << str;

      string d_str = get_value_name_from_value_id(stgs[i].settingId, (unsigned int)stgs[i].u32CurrentValue);

      out << YAML::Key << "value";
      out << YAML::Value << d_str;

      out << YAML::EndMap;
  }
}

out << YAML::EndSeq;

f_out << out.c_str();
```

and I'm getting:

```
- name: <some_name>
  value: <some_value>
```

I tried adding

```
out << YAML::NewLine;
```

at the beginning of the map, but it gives the wrong result. How can I get the output I want?

Comment: The format you want is not valid yaml.

Comment: why?? [http://www.yaml.org/](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963)

Comment: Indentation matters in yaml. Did you want it to look like example 2.4 in your link?

Comment: Oh, thanks! I fix it. Yes, like in 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `YAML::Newline` just *after* `YAML::BeginMap` to get the newline after the `-` but before the first entry of the map:

```
out << YAML::BeginMap;
out << YAML::Newline;

out << YAML::Key << "name";
out << YAML::Value << str;

out << YAML::Key << "value";
out << YAML::Value << d_str;

out << YAML::EndMap;
```